# How to exclude a foreign's key field from a form

Tags: django, forms

Having my models Yacht and Offer, I created an intermediate table OfferHasYacht in order to connect a yacht with an offer. I have already created instances for both models.

I want to exclude in my form the field date_created from the Offer model because when I am trying to included it in my form it gives an error of :

**TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type datetime.datetime)**

In order to avoid this, I want to exclude only this field and not the notes field from my offer model.

How can I do that?

models.py

```
class Yacht(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
    price_per_day=models.DecimalField("Price(€) / Day", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0,blank=True)
    passengers = models.IntegerField("Passengers",blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Offer(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField("Date of Offer", null=True,blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    notes=models.CharField("Notes",max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date_created




class OfferHasYacht(models.Model):
    offer=models.ForeignKey(Offer,null=True,verbose_name="Offer",on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    yacht=models.ForeignKey(Yacht,null=True,verbose_name="Yacht",on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.yacht.name
```

forms.py

```
class OfferHasYachtForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OfferHasYacht
        #exclude=('',)
        fields = ('yacht','offer',)
```

With this solution it raises the error :TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type datetime.datetime)

**How can I exclude the date_created field of Offer model?**
**or How can I handle date_created field for not raising this error?**

Comment: try return str(self.date_created)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `auto_now_add=True` on the model it will handle everything by itself.

Comment: replace the `null=True,blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now` with the above.

Comment: It was the return that created the problem. I fix it to def __str__(self):
  return  self.notes + " at " + str(self.date_created)

Comment: Perfect, but I still prefer to use `auto_now_add=True` :D